# Angularjs simple file download causes router to redirect

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<a href="mysite.com/uploads/asd4a4d5a.pdf" download="foo.pdf">
```

Uploads get a unique file name while there real name is kept in database. I want to realize a simple file download. But the code above redirects to / because of:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/', 
    controller: MainController
});
```

I tried with

```
$scope.download = function(resource){
    window.open(resource);
}
```

but this just opens the file in a new window.

Any ideas how to enable a real download for any file type?

Comment: did you try `target="_blank"` or `target="_self"`? See: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#htmllinkrewriting

Comment: @MoritzPetersen target="_self" works great, make this an answer please

Comment: Please accept jessegavins answer, as I couldn't have written it better.

Comment: Moritz, the link is now broken - should be https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting

Answer (score 114, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain target element Example:
>     `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain Example:
>     `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
> - Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined    Example:
>     `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

So in your case, you should add a target attribute like so...

```
<a target="_self" href="example.com/uploads/asd4a4d5a.pdf" download="foo.pdf">
```

Comment: Absolute URL will not work if the link is pointing to the same site.

Comment: This is a great answer. Now I just have to figure out how to do this with a button and a POST 8-/

Comment: @Snekse If you need to do a file download with a button and a POST, just create a regular <form> tag and a <button type="submit"> like they did way back in 1996

Comment: :-)   I was afraid you were going to say that.  I was trying to avoid a form since all the data I'm posting was generated and not user input.

Comment: One point to note, `download` is not supported by IE or Safari.

Comment: `download` may not be fully supported, but the browser will still open the pdf in another window that will allow you to download it. Pretty good fallback. My problem is what if you need an on-click event on the same `a`?

Comment: it is fairly to `Angular 2`!:)

Answer (score 32):

We also had to develop a solution which would even work with APIs requiring authentication (see [this article](https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/an-angularjs-directive-to-download-pdf-files))

Using AngularJS in a nutshell here is how we did it:

Step 1: Create a dedicated directive

```
// jQuery needed, uses Bootstrap classes, adjust the path of templateUrl
app.directive('pdfDownload', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/path/to/pdfDownload.tpl.html',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var anchor = element.children()[0];

        // When the download starts, disable the link
        scope.$on('download-start', function() {
            $(anchor).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });

        // When the download finishes, attach the data to the link. Enable the link and change its appearance.
        scope.$on('downloaded', function(event, data) {
            $(anchor).attr({
                href: 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data,
                download: attr.filename
            })
                .removeAttr('disabled')
                .text('Save')
                .removeClass('btn-primary')
                .addClass('btn-success');

            // Also overwrite the download pdf function to do nothing.
            scope.downloadPdf = function() {
            };
        });
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', '$http', function($scope, $attrs, $http) {
        $scope.downloadPdf = function() {
            $scope.$emit('download-start');
            $http.get($attrs.url).then(function(response) {
                $scope.$emit('downloaded', response.data);
            });
        };
    }] 
});
```

Step 2: Create a template

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadPdf()">Download</a>
```

Step 3: Use it

```
<pdf-download url="/some/path/to/a.pdf" filename="my-awesome-pdf"></pdf-download>
```

This will render a blue button. When clicked, a PDF will be downloaded (Caution: the backend has to deliver the PDF in Base64 encoding!) and put into the href. The button turns green and switches the text to *Save*. The user can click again and will be presented with a standard download file dialog for the file *my-awesome.pdf*.

Our example uses PDF files, but apparently you could provide any binary format given it's properly encoded.

Comment: Nice solution, but there are two limitations: 1. The user has to click the button twice, 2. IE 11 does not support the download attribute, so you can't set a filename.

Comment: What about big files? 1GB? 10GB?

Answer (score 8):

If you need a directive more advanced, I recomend the solution that I implemnted, correctly tested on Internet Explorer 11, Chrome and FireFox.

I hope it, will be helpfull.

HTML :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" file-name="'fileName.extension'"  ng-click="getFile()" file-download="myBlobObject"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></a>
```

DIRECTIVE :

```
directive('fileDownload',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            fileDownload:'=',
            fileName:'=',
        },

        link:function(scope,elem,atrs){


            scope.$watch('fileDownload',function(newValue, oldValue){

                if(newValue!=undefined && newValue!=null){
                    console.debug('Downloading a new file'); 
                    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
                    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
                    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
                    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
                    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
                    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
                    var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

                    if(isFirefox || isIE || isChrome){
                        if(isChrome){
                            console.log('Manage Google Chrome download');
                            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var fileURL = url.createObjectURL(scope.fileDownload);
                            var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');//create a new  <a> tag element
                            downloadLink.attr('href',fileURL);
                            downloadLink.attr('download',scope.fileName);
                            downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
                            downloadLink[0].click();//call click function
                            url.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);//revoke the object from URL
                        }
                        if(isIE){
                            console.log('Manage IE download>10');
                            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(scope.fileDownload,scope.fileName); 
                        }
                        if(isFirefox){
                            console.log('Manage Mozilla Firefox download');
                            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var fileURL = url.createObjectURL(scope.fileDownload);
                            var a=elem[0];//recover the <a> tag from directive
                            a.href=fileURL;
                            a.download=scope.fileName;
                            a.target='_self';
                            a.click();//we call click function
                        }


                    }else{
                        alert('SORRY YOUR BROWSER IS NOT COMPATIBLE');
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
})
```

IN CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.myBlobObject=undefined;
$scope.getFile=function(){
        console.log('download started, you can show a wating animation');
        serviceAsPromise.getStream({param1:'data1',param1:'data2', ...})
        .then(function(data){//is important that the data was returned as Aray Buffer
                console.log('Stream download complete, stop animation!');
                $scope.myBlobObject=new Blob([data],{ type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
        },function(fail){
                console.log('Download Error, stop animation and show error message');
                                    $scope.myBlobObject=[];
                                });
                            };
```

IN SERVICE:

```
function getStream(params){
                 console.log("RUNNING");
                 var deferred = $q.defer();

                 $http({
                     url:'../downloadURL/',
                     method:"PUT",//you can use also GET or POST
                     data:params,
                     headers:{'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                     responseType : 'arraybuffer',//THIS IS IMPORTANT
                    })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        console.debug("SUCCESS");
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).error(function (data) {
                         console.error("ERROR");
                         deferred.reject(data);
                    });

                 return deferred.promise;
                };
```

BACKEND(on SPRING):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadURL/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void downloadExcel(HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody Map<String,String> spParams
        ) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outStream=null;
outStream = response.getOutputStream();//is important manage the exceptions here
ObjectThatWritesOnOutputStream myWriter= new ObjectThatWritesOnOutputStream();// note that this object doesn exist on JAVA,
ObjectThatWritesOnOutputStream.write(outStream);//you can configure more things here
outStream.flush();
return;
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly:  the entire file to download is read into the Javascript dataspace, and then passed to the Browser to write to the local file?  Imagine the data is 1GB or more; I think that using the simple <a> tag above will be streamed by the browser incrementally. I'm not sure bringing the all the data into a single arraystring is practical in my case.

Comment: Yes that is correct, a simple <a> tag could be used, but in my case I implemented this for two reasons, the first reason is, in my case I need to build  an excel dinamically with data from database; and the second reason is that a simple <a> tag doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

in template

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-warn md-ink-ripple" ng-click="export()" aria-label="Export">
<md-icon class="material-icons" alt="Export" title="Export" aria-label="Export">
    system_update_alt
</md-icon></md-button>
```

in controller

```
     $scope.export = function(){ $window.location.href = $scope.export; };
```