# Angular.js Click on link to download is causing navigate to home page

Tags: angularjs, onclick, download, href, angularjs-routing

Here is what I have

```
<div quick-list>
    <br quick-link icon='download-alt' href='{{ getDownloadLink(assignment) }}' text="getMessage('assignmentListStudent.attachment.action.download')">
</div>
```

The concerned function for this is as follows

```
$scope.getDownloadLink = function(assignment) {

    if (!assignment || !assignment.userAttachment || !assignment.userAttachment[0] ) {
        return '';
    }

    return assignment.userAttachment[0].path.replace("equella/items", "equella/force-download/items");
};
```

I am not sure what is wrong here but the moment I click on the download link, I see that the page navigates to the home page where as it should be downloading an existing file. 
This is what I see in chrome.

```
 <li class="quick-link ng-scope" quick-link="" icon="download-alt" href="/community/proxy/equella/force-download/items/71c1f5d5-8a1f-4e85-84d6-7560a9e01b63/1/hanks.tomha.24066.PNG" text="getMessage('assignmentListStudent.attachment.action.download')"><a href="/community/proxy/equella/force-download/items/71c1f5d5-8a1f-4e85-84d6-7560a9e01b63/1/hanks.tomha.24066.PNG" class="ng-binding kb-mode"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i>Download</a></li>
```

Reality Student Central (5-15) UPDATED titleInSequence

Is there anything that i'm doing wrong? Should I change something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your router is likely redirecting you to the homepage.

See [Angularjs simple file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download)