# Download local files using href

Tags: html, download, href

I made a web app using Java (jersey servlets on backend) and AngularJs on frontend. I want to open in new tabs or download some local files. I tried using:

```
<a href="file:///{{course.path}}" target="_blank" ><span> {{course.filename}} </span></a>
```

where course is JSON like:

```
{type: "pdf", path: "C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/Courses/course2.pdf", areaSubject: "It", created: 1434700150341, filename: "course2"}
```

When I click on it, it opens a blank page (about:blank) and nothing appears.When I type on browser `file:///C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/Courses/course2.pdf` the content appears.
How can I make it works when click  tag? I use Chrome.

Comment: You could try ng-href https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: <a href="file:///{{course.path}}" target="_blank" download ><span> {{course.filename}} </span></a>   try this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download

Comment: @ThomasM, did you find the solution?