# Angular JS file download

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am trying to download file on a link click following this stackoverflow question [Angularjs simple file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download). After i click the link file downloads with error saying **Failed No file**. I have checked projects App_Data folder file is present there. Can anyone help figure out the issue.

```
 <a target="_self" download="{{q.FileName}}" ng-href="{{q.QuizFile}}" href="#">Open File</a>
```

It renders into this path...

```
<a target="_self" download="Discussion.docx" ng-href="~/App_Data/74edf10b-5c18-472f-92bb-c64f55575b29/Discussion.docx" href="~/App_Data/74edf10b-5c18-472f-92bb-c64f55575b29/Discussion.docx">Open File</a>
```

Comment: your app_data folder has an equivalent URL? Something like http://localhost/app_data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilde in the path name doesn't mean anything in JavaScript. Its a convenience in mvc that resolves server side. Pass the path without the tilde.