# How to create an image button to enable file download in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, download

I have an image shown below and I want to make it into a button where you can download files. I have seen examples on how to download such as [Angularjs simple file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download)
but this didn't work for me.

```
<li ng-init="imgsrc_local='../img/local.png'"></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use button tag and an img with ng-src pointing out to your image path, like this:

```
<button><img ng-src="../img/local.png"/></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use md-button and md-icon using angular material

```
<md-button class="md-fab">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="path"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

To use this you have to add angular_material.js script to your html
You can install it using bower command

```
bower install angular-material
```

Then add this to your html file

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```