# How to download All types of files using angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
    In my Table has different types of files like
    Excel sheets , PDF files, word files, different types of images

I need to download any type of file , when i click an anchor tag
```

How to download All types of files using angular js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs simple file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514509/how-do-you-serve-a-file-for-download-with-angularjs-or-javascript