# How to download the file using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have uploaded a file as an object. My object seems like below,

```
{
filename:"angular",
desc:"opensource",
myfile{
         name:"Angular-JS-ppt.pptx",
         size:3057359,
         type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
      }
}
```

Likewise i have number of objects stored. 
Now, my query is, how to download the data based on the file clicked, as i have all the details like name,size,type.Any answer or hint,great help. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this link: [Angular file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download). It may help you to download the file.

Comment: I have looked those, but vain. so, rather than those any answer will help me great