# How to create a fillable and savable form using pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf

I want to create a fillable user form than user can download that form then fill the form and upload it. When user upload i'll extract the data and save in database using angularjs.

Comment: Fillable and savable in which pdf viewers? In which versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link to create a form in java-script:
https://www.formget.com/javascript-contact-form/

Check this already created thread to download and upload a file in angular JS:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm
[Angularjs simple file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670754/angularjs-simple-file-download)

Comment: Good first answer!. However, Improve the readability. Help if there is any code snippet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i want to create pdf form that i can download and fill offline and save.Then upload it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a PDF that contains a form in many different ways :

- use Adobe Acrobat or other creation tools that have a graphical user interface
- use an SDK that supports creating PDF forms programmatically
- create an HTML form and convert it to PDF

Pick one that works for you and go with it, there doesn't have to be programming involved with that piece at all unless you want there to be. Just please don't use XFA forms, stick with Acroforms (for further info check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#AcroForms) for the differences between XFA and Acroforms).

**Distributing PDFs that contain forms**

When distributing PDFs that contain forms though, you need to understand that forms have spotty support in various PDF viewing applications. Apple's Preview tends to damage PDFs that contain forms that use JavaScript. Web browsers are hit or miss on how much interaction they support with PDF forms. Adobe Reader (the free PDF viewing application from Adobe) allows users to fill in a form and restricts the users ability to save that filled in form, see next section for more info. Adobe Acrobat (the paid PDF viewing/editing application from Adobe) allows users to fill in and save a PDF that contains a form.

**Reader Enablement/Reader Extensions**

In the Adobe PDF ecosystem, there is a line drawn between what is supported in Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat. Unfortunately forms got the short end of the stick and are best supported out of the box in Adobe Acrobat which means users of the form have to have Adobe Acrobat which costs money. To remedy this, Adobe came up with a way to enable this functionality in Adobe Reader and move the cost from the end user to whoever is distributing the form referred to either as *Reader Extensions* or *Reader Enablement*.

(This is how the IRS in the United States is able to distribute PDFs that contain forms and not require that everyone who files taxes in the US needs to have Adobe Acrobat to use the [electronic forms](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf).)

If you are distributing a PDF that contains a form that you would like your users to be able to fill in without requiring the use of Adobe Acrobat (the paid one), then you will need to Reader Enable/Reader Extend the PDF. Read through the Adobe [help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-distributing-pdf-forms.html#enable_reader_users_to_save_form_data) on this and take careful note of which version of Adobe Acrobat supports what. Hidden in the EULA for Adobe Acrobat is or used to be a line that restricted the number of forms that could be Reader Enabled/Reader Extended or the number of people you could distribute the forms to.

If this is a large scale type situation, then get in contact with someone who can sell you a license to support what you need.

Comment: Whether or not Reader enabling is necessary depends on the Reader versions to support. Newer Reader versions allow more interactivity without the need for that.

Comment: i have created a form using LiveCycle Designer 8.0 and also able to save the fields in PDF format.But how to get the form data when user uploads using angularjs. I'm not sending the file to any server just want to get the field data.